# Can you include a division in a window function (redshift)

Tags: sql, window, aggregate, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I am looking a consultant dataset and want to use a window function to calculate a ratio per consultant.
I want to know how many sales the consultant made, when they called a customer

```
select
"consultant", "country",
(count(case when "sales"=1 then "call id" end) / count(case when "call to"='customer' then "call id" end)
over (partition by "consultant" order by "consultant") as "Sales Ratio"
from consultant
group by 1,2
```

Table that I am using:               [image: consultant]

Now I am doubting I can use a window function in this case. The error that I get is: The database reported a syntax error: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "over" Position: 3191;

Comment: you have the "then" word .(j)ust before  over.  but you have not condition to test .. try remove this word

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry, how would you write the window function in my case?

Comment: Please show the results you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure what you mean, but I am not getting results because of the error I posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how many sales the consultant made, when they called a customer

I'm a little confused where the window functions come in.  This sounds like conditional aggregation:

```
select "consultant", 
       sum(case when sales = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_sales,
       sum(case when sales = 1 and "call to" = 'customer' then 1 else 0 end) as num_sales_with_call,
       sum(case when sales = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) / sum(case when "call to" = 'customer' then 1 end) as sales_to_call_ratio
from consultant
group by 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `OVER` clause for both of the analytical function separately and please make sure that divider is greater than 0 or use appropriate condition to avoid divide by zero.

```
select "consultant", 
       "country",
       count(case when "sales"=1 then 1 end) over (partition by "consultant")
        / count(case when "call to"='customer' then 1 end) over (partition by "consultant") as "Sales Ratio"
from consultant
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Good point, I added nullif to account for that case: ```select "consultant", 
       "country",
       count(case when "sales"=1 then 1 end) over (partition by "consultant")
        / (Nullif(count(case when "call to"='customer' then 1 end) over (partition by "consultant")),0) as "Sales Ratio"
from consultant
group by 1,2```